# Calculate array sum by given array only, without passing it's length

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to calculate array sum, but attribute must be ONLY this particular array.

```
bool solution(int arr[]) {
    int counter = 0;
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::cout << len << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++){
        counter += arr[i];
    }
    if (counter == 21)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

It won't work, I need to pass an array length from outside.
how to reach this without passing array length as an attribute?

Comment: You can't.  Arrays decay to pointers when passed into a function.

Comment: Why the restriction on not passing in the size?  That's the preferred way to do it.

Comment: In C++ one solution is to use a `std::vector`. It knows its own size.

Comment: How do you know how many numbers to sum without passing a length or quantity?  Remember, I could have an array of 32 but only 10 slots are filled.

Comment: Pass the address of the array to  `bool solution(int (*arr)[42]) {`.  Of course, if the array count is not 42, then a compile time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to reach this without passing array length as an attribute?

You cannot unless your array holds a sentinel value that marks the end of valid numbers.

Use `std::vector` if you have the option to. Then, the size information comes along for the ride.